# InvalidChangeBatch 400: "" is not a valid hosted zone id. is not a valid encrypted identifier when attempting to add A record to existing domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53, domain-name

I am attempting to point my domain to my S3 bucket

When I attempt to create an A record on my domain I get the following error in Route53 console:

```
Error occurred
Alias Target contains an invalid value.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: "" is not a valid hosted zone id. is not a valid encrypted identifier)
```

[image]

I note that when I select "ap-southeast-2" my "bowls-holdingpage" bucket doesn't pre-populate even although it's definitely in that region and setup to host a static site. It is hosting the site on the default S3 endpoint URL, but I am trying to switch it over to add an A record on my domain.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem as well.
I did have the bucket named the same as the domain.

What I found was about an hour after I had created the bucket, it suddenly became available in the 'Choose S3 bucket' drop down.

Another thing I missed on the bucket set up was at first I didn't enable static website hosting in 'Static website hosting'.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, i'll try this out this weekend and come back and confirm.

Comment: I confirm that the "static website hosting" setting is indeed needed.

Comment: tl;dr "Wait" :-)

Answer (score 7):

I got this error message when trying to create a Route53 DNS A Record that points to a CloudFront distribution. (This is currently the top Google result for that error message.)

I had assumed (incorrectly) that one needed to put the Hosted Zone of the *CloudFront distribution* into the Record, because the Record expects a Hosted Zone in its AliasTarget. But actually I needed to put in a special magic value (!) of `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2` from [the Route53 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html):

```
session = aioboto3.Session(...)
async with session.client('route53') as route53:
    route53_response = await route53.change_resource_record_sets(
        HostedZoneId=route53_hosted_zone_id,  # ex: A9E7TNDATAW749
        ChangeBatch={
            'Comment': f'CloudFront distribution for {domain_name}',
            'Changes': [
                {
                    'Action': 'CREATE',
                    'ResourceRecordSet': {
                        'Name': domain_name,  # ex: mysubdomain.example.com
                        'Type': 'A',
                        'AliasTarget': {
                            # https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html
                            'HostedZoneId': 'Z2FDTNDATAQYW2',  #  magic, for a CloudFront distribution
                            'DNSName': cloudfront_distribution_domain_name,  # ex: q1a91r2o7y8g32.cloudfront.net
                            'EvaluateTargetHealth': False,
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    )
```

Comment: This worked for me and I'm very surprised that this was fix.  I tried multiple things and removing the HostedZoneId but only this worked.

Answer (score 2):

To use R53 for buckets, the bucket name must match your domain. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html):

> Amazon S3 bucket – The name of the **record must match the name of your Amazon S3 bucket**. For example, if the name of your bucket is acme.example.com, the name of this record must also be acme.example.com. In addition, you must configure the bucket for **website** hosting.

So your bucket should be called `bowls.com.au`

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for this. This helps, and I have resolved the error by using the full endpoint of the bucket. But the domain is still no resolving in the browser. rockybowls.com.au A record routes traffic to rockybowls.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com. in Route 53 which is correctly setup as a static website in S3 as this URL is accessible: http://rockybowls.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com. Am I forgot about something here?

Comment: @crmpicco That should be enough. Is the domain `rockybowls.com.au` managed by R53, or you got it outside of AWS?

Comment: @crmpicco On the screenshot, you have `bowls.com.au`, but in the comment you wrote about `rockybowls.com.au`? Are these same, or different?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I was attempting to obfuscate the domain to begin with. rockybowls.com.au is the real domain.

Comment: @crmpicco Don't know what else could be wrong. The only thing I recommend is to double check all the settings for the domain. You could also make new question with details specific to this new issue.